# Django: blocktrans not working anymore

Tags: django, internationalization

In my current project `blocktrans` is not working anymore (it used to work just fine). `trans` or one-line-`blocktrans` work just fine, only multi-line-`blocktrans` fail. `django-admin.py makemessages` still picks all these messages up correctly, but in the output the default (en) language will be shown instead of the translated.

Using the python shell I can retrieve the translation. It's the template/localization where system doesn't seem to retrieve the translations. Inside `python manage.py shell`:

```
from django.utils import translation
s = "the text"
translation.activate('en')
translation.ugettext(s) # gets the default text
translation.activate('hi')
translation.ugettext(s) # gets the correct translated text
```

- The messages are not fuzzy
- I tried to make the translation have as many lines as the original

I'm still on django 1.1

What could I be missing/doing wrong?